# Getting y from x co-ord for cubic bezier curve, fast Newton-Raphson method

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, bezier, numerical-stability

Given the points of a Bezier curve (P0, P1, P2, P3) in 2D, I would like to find the y co-ordinate for a given x co-ordinate. The problem is well defined because of the following restrictions:

- P0 = (0,0), P3 = (1,1)
- P1 = (t, 1-t) for t between 0, 1
- P2 = 1 - P1 (x and y)

I have the following function to calculate the answer, having put in all the restrictions
above into the Bezier curve formula here [CubicBezier.html](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/bezier/cubicbezier.html). I am using Newton-Raphson to work out the parameter of the point I want, and I know this works as I don't let the loop finish until it has (within defined tolerance).

I am using this function to apply a contrast filter to an image. For this 0.5 gives the same image back, 0.0 does max reduction in contrast and 1.0 does max increase.

**EDIT** The following function has been corrected and now works perfectly.

```
/*
 * Parameters: p - x co-ord of P1, 
 *             x - x we want to find y for
 *
 * This method is unstable for p ~= 0.5, maybe needs refinement.
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#define ITER_TOL  0.00001

float maths::bezier(float p, float x)
{
    if(p < 0.f || p > 1.f || x < 0.f || x > 1.f)
    {
        std::cerr << "Both parameters must be between 0 and 1, returning dummy value" << std::endl;
        return 0.f;
    }
    //First guess for u
    float u = x;
    //Coefficients of curve (for x and y co-ord)
    float x3 = 6 * p - 2;
    float x2 = 3 - 9 * p;
    float x1 = 3 * p;
    float x0 = -x;

    float y3 = 6 * (1-p) - 2;
    float y2 = 3 - 9 * (1-p);
    float y1 = 3 * (1-p);

    //Newton-Raphson refinement
    for(int i=0; fabs(x3*u*u*u + x2*u*u + x1*u + x0) > ITER_TOL && i<1000; i++)
    {
        u = u - (x3*u*u*u + x2*u*u + x1*u + x0) /
                (3*x3*u*u + 2*x2*u + x1);
        //std::cout << i << ": " << u << std::endl;
        //Deal with non-convergence
        if(i==999)
        {
            std::cerr << "Warning, Newton-Raphson method did not converge in Maths.cpp, returning dummy" << std::endl;
            return 0.f;
        }
    }
    //Calculate y co-ord
    return y3*u*u*u + y2*u*u + y1*u;
}
```

If we set p = 0.5, we should get a straight line, but when I do this for a linspace
and plot the points, I get a bend between 0.5 and 1.0. Can anyone see why this is happening, and if there is anything I can do about it?

Comment: Here is code for test `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "[";
    for(float i=0; i<1; i+=0.01)
        std::cout << maths::bezierContrast(0.5, i) << ", ";
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}`

Comment: I am also interested in suggestions of how to do the getting y from x better. I know about direct solve and midpoint iteration, but the first is unstable and complex (in every sense of the word) and the second is slow and inelegant.

Comment: I think there should be `fabs` somewhere near `ITER_TOL` in the convergence check.

Comment: I think that the lhs of that is forced to be >0, but i'll try adding fabs and see if it helps :).

Comment: That solved the problem! You are a hero.

Comment: I tried to add that as the answer but can't as i have under 100 rep and haven't waited 8 hours since asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled your code and noticed that the loop runs only 0 or 1 iterations. Probably it's because a `fabs` is missing somewhere in the convergence check?